# How can i produce a BIOS BEEP from the BUILD IN speaker using a common scripting language?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, autohotkey, windows-7-x64

I want to produce a beep like the bios beep from the build in speaker when a computer starts NOT FROM THE SPEAKERS. I use windows 7 64bit. Tried many things but everything beeps in my headphones/speakers.

Third party software is acceptable also.

Comment: Shall I assume that you have tried `WshShell.Run "cmd /c @echo " & chr(007), 0` in vbscript? To stop the assuming and wasting peoples time you should show us what you have tried.

Comment: Most computers now don't even *have* a built-in speaker, which is why the BEEP.SYS driver was removed in Windows Vista.

Comment: @Matt i tried with the vbscript even before i tried it i disabled my sound card and restarted my computer and then i ran the script and nothing happened. Otherwise when my sound card is enabled i can hear the beep in my headphones.

Comment: Check out this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
copy con con
Ctrl + G (it will look ^G)
Ctrl + Z
```

On Win 9.x you'll need to disable sound card first.

Comment: I searched in google for couple of hours and such solutions does not work, it produces a sound in my headphones.
PS: I also tried disabling my sound card.

Comment: Beeps my speaker. Does your computer have a speaker to beep. A lot of modern ones don't. The beep driver/service has to be running of course. `sc query beep` and `sc qc beep`.

Comment: Beep is in vista. Copy it from Vista, it might work.

Comment: Im sure i have a speaker it beeps when my pc starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been searching in google, you may now know it, but ...

In short, no, can not do it, or, at least, you can not do it from a scripting language

From Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> In Windows 7, Beep was rewritten to pass the beep to the default sound
> device for the session. This is normally the sound card, except when
> run under Terminal Services, in which case the beep is rendered on the
> client.

And [here, why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7) this works that way

All the alternatives involve machine reconfiguration and/or driver replacements (see [here](http://www.waldbauer.com/tmp/reference.php))

Comment: I've red both articles and tried the method (without result) before posting here. I just hope someone shows a way of doing this. I edited my post because third party software is also acceptable, i just want it to work.